# IE7 - Prevent unresponsive script error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is used as a visual filter on an application I'm building.  Basically, when a user types something into the textbox with id 'filter', the code below runs to hide those that match.

```
$('#filter').keyup(function() {
        delay(function(){
            $(".patient:not(:contains('" + $('#filter').val() + "'))").fadeOut();
            $(".patient:contains('" + $('#filter').val() + "')").fadeIn();
        }, 300 );
        });
```

The code works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE7 two things happen that I don't like:-

1)  The selected divs dont fadeOut/In - they just appear..
2)  Occasionally, I get an error from IE that the script is taking too long and may become unresponsive.

In terms of problem 2 I've read that returning control to the browser (again maybe using a timeout) might prevent the issue but I'm not sure if this is possible using my code or how to do it.

Can you guys help?

(PS - for the record, I HAVE to use IE7 in my organisation.  Bad, I know, but I can do nothing about this, just in case your solutions involve changing browser :))

Comment: maybe post your html as well ?

Comment: The HTML is dead simple, just contains a bunch of divs with class patient.  They contain some other stuff but it's the fact that the code allows visual filtering by content..

Comment: your bug can also be dead simple, but we won't be able to see it if we can't see the whole context. Post your html

Comment: Unfortunately Im unable to do this.  The HTML content is confidential.  This is why I had to describe the structure as per my previous comment - it really is simple.  The HTML is dynamically generated and there can be any number of divs with the patient class.  There are no issues with the HTML, just the code in IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it and prevent the errors.  Maybe I was just asking too much of the browser, so I changed the code as follows:-

```
$('#filter').keyup(function() {
        delay(function(){
            $(".patient").hide();
            $(".patient:contains('" + $('#filter').val() + "')").fadeIn();
        }, 300 );
        });
```

This now works pretty much perfectly.